# Git - parse id of nth commit

Tags: git

let's say we have the last 5 commits:

```
git log -n 5

xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyy # <== this is what I want
```

#### how can I get **only** the **`ID`** of the `yyyyyyyyy` commit?

```
git rev-parse HEAD # will return the HEAD commit id, how can I say -5?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rev-parse HEAD~5` (or ~4, not sure which one you want).

It will traverse using the first parent in case of merge commit.

You'll find more info here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Answer (score 1):

If it's the 5th commit in the output of `git log`,

```
git log --oneline --pretty=%H -5 | sed -n 5p
```

`HEAD~4` may not be the 5th commit in the output of `git log` if the history is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you're looking for is postfixed `~` (and a number)

```
HEAD~5
```

refers to the n-th ancestor of `HEAD` commit.

Not to be confused with postfixed `^` which means n-th parent of designated commit (a commit can have more than 2 parents).

If the number is omitted, it's assumed as 1.

(That's also the reason why `HEAD^` and `HEAD~` are refering to the same commit.)

Check the very informative [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) on the subject.